# Will increasing the precision and scale of a decimal column impact existing index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, precision

I have a table on SQL Server with over 100 million rows and quite heavily used. I'm looking at increasing the decimal precision and scale of one of the columns, which also has a non-clustered index. When changing precision/scale, is it also recommended to drop the index before updating precision/scale, followed by recreating an index (something like in the snippet below for example). Basically not entirely sure what sort of impact altering the field would have on the index - is the drop + recreation an overkill?

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS [IX_Index] ON [dbo].[TableName]
ALTER TABLE dbo.[TableName]
ALTER COLUMN DecimalField DECIMAL(14, 9) NOT NULL
                    
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name='IX_Index' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName'))
BEGIN
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Index] ON [dbo].[TableName]
    (
        DecimalField ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
END
```

Comment: I think you'll find it's not a matter of *choice*. You cannot change the data type (and choosing different values for precision or scale is changing the data type) without dropping the index first.

Comment: Ah, the line was a bit blur whether we are changing the data type or not by altering precision/scale. Thanks so much, that's very helpful!

Comment: @ComputerScientist: specifically, for the engine the relevant bit is that changing scale/precision changes the binary representation of the value, so an index rewrite would be unavoidable in any case. The same does not apply when, for example, a `VARCHAR` field is made longer, so this is allowed without dropping the index first (but not *shorter*, because that might involve truncating).